# Coalescing multiple rows into a single row

Tags: python, algorithm

This was a particularity hard problem I had on my final exam and I was unable to figure out the solution. Its been bothering me for several days now and I figured I would post on here for some guidance / advice.

The problem goes as follows: You have a list(a) of tuples which are strings and numbers. The question says to "iterate over the data set, appending the values of rows with empty strings to the most recent non-empty string's value set". The final result is supposed to look like the b array

```
a = [
    ('Hello', 1),
    ('', 2),
    ('', 3),
    ('', 4),
    ('World', 1),
    ('', 2)]

b = [
    ("Hello", [1, 2, 3, 4]),
    ("World", [1, 2])]


data = iter(a)

for row in data:
    lastKey = ''
    carryValues = []

    if not row[0] == '':
        lastKey = row[0]
    else:
        while row[0] == '':
            carryValues.append(row[1])
            row = next(data, None)

    print(lastKey, carryValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

The idea is to use a dictionary to store all the values belonging to each string in a list, and then to iterate over the keys of the dictionary

```
last_key = ''
sol_dict = {}
lst =  [
    ('Hello', 1),
    ('', 2),
    ('', 3),
    ('', 4),
    ('World', 1),
    ('', 2)]


for tup in lst:
    if tup[0] != '':
        last_key = tup[0]
        sol_dict[last_key] = [tup[1]]
    else:
        sol_dict[last_key].append(tup[1])


result_list = []

for key in list(sol_dict.keys()):
    result_list.append((key,sol_dict[key]))

print (result_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [
('Hello', 1),
('', 2),
('', 3),
('', 4),
('World', 1),
('', 2)] 

b = []

i = 0

for row in a:
    if row[0]!='':
        b.append((row[0], [row[1]]))
        i = i + 1
    else:
        b[i-1][1].append(row[1])
print(b)
```

output:

```
[('Hello', [1, 2, 3, 4]), ('World', [1, 2])]
```